# MySQL select statement for retrieving user role permissions

Tags: sql, mysql, database, query-selector

I have a java project that I'm working on and I'm trying to implement in my application role-based authentication.
 So for example when a user is logging and he is an admin he will have access to some extra methods then a normal user has access to.

In order to do that I've mapped my database in the following way.

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Table structure for table `data`
--

USE DB;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id_u` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Salt` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   `Role` int(30)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_u`)
);

--
-- Dumping data for table `data`
--

INSERT INTO `data` (`id_u`,`Username`, `Password`, `Salt`,`Role`) VALUES
(1,'Mike', 'TzBql1WR9wZjN0LoKr2OBk2majc=', '4NWwJULan8U=','1'), 
(2,'John', 'JcQnEVl0af8EwrPkmc6EGG+fLfs=', '2MWwJULan8U=','1'), 
(3,'Alice', 'BaN+yn8W0SYZiUkaOHSZxDKTLMg=', '4NWSJULgn8U=','2'),
(4,'Bob', 'V1TtSe0GFYuHFJrA1l1lDIwdfKA=', '4NWwJILan9U=','2'),  
(5,'Charlie', 'X40Xv/MntGoeqwif8hhFEOIrK8Q=', '4NWwFULan8X=','2');
COMMIT;

--
-- Table structure for table `Roles`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Roles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Roles` (
  `id_r` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Role_type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Role_code` int(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_r`),
   CONSTRAINT FK_UsersRoles FOREIGN KEY (Role_code)
   REFERENCES Roles(Role),
   CONSTRAINT FK_PermissionsRoles FOREIGN KEY (Role_code)
   REFERENCES Permissions(Permission)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Roles`
--

INSERT INTO `Roles` (`id_r`, `Role_type`, `Role_code`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 1),
(2, 'normaluser', 2),
(3, 'guest', 3);
COMMIT;


--
-- Table structure for table `Permissions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Permissions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Permissions` (
  `id_p` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Function` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Permission` int(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_p`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Permissions`
--

INSERT INTO `Permissions` (`id_p`, `Function`, `Permission`) VALUES
(1, 'newPrintJob', 0),
(2, 'print', 3),
(3, 'start', 3),
(4, 'read config', 2),
(5, 'set config', 1),
(6, 'queue', 2),
(7, 'top queue',2 ),
(8, 'stop', 2),
(9, 'restart', 2),
(10, 'status', 3),
(11, 'createUser', 1);
(12, 'createUser', 2);
```

Now my questions are, does the database have the correct structure in order to retrieve the name of the function in the Permission table?

How can I write a select statement that will retrieve a list of the certain functions from table Permission that a certain user has?
Any other feedback would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: *How can I write a select statement that will retrieve a list of the certain functions* - this is out of scope